# Convolution is continuous

Tags: continuity, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, convolution

> Convolution is continuous

Let $f,g\in L^2\left(\mathbb T,\mathbb C\right)$ (Hilbert space of $1$-periodic functions) then $f*g$ should be continuous by Young's inequality (the map is $(f,g)\mapsto f*g$)

$$\big\lvert f*g(x)-f*g(z)\big\rvert=\left\lvert\int_0^1f(y)\left(g(x-y)-g(z-y)\right)dy\right\rvert.$$

Do you have an idea how to apply the inequality now?

Comment: I would apply Hölder's inequality and use the fact that $\|g(\cdot+h)-g(\cdot)\|_{L^{p}}\rightarrow 0$ for $p\in[1,\infty)$ and $h\rightarrow 0$. This result can be show by approximating the $L^{p}$ function by a smooth function...but it does not use Young's inequality :)!